# I'm trying to add an image of Shrek using JOptionPane on eclipse but the the photo doesn't show on the GUI interface

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

```
private void shrek() {
    ImageIcon originalIcon = new ImageIcon("shrek.jpeg");
    Image iconImage = originalIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(400,400,0);
    ImageIcon okIcon = new ImageIcon(iconImage);
    Object textArea = null;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea, "Shrek", 
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, okIcon);
}
```

// everything else works except for this part

I've never really done Gui before so I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: `new ImageIcon("shrek.jpeg")` assumes that `shrek.jpeg` is in the current WORKING directory.  I would consider using `ImageIO.read` over `ImageIcon` as it will throw an exception when the image can't be loaded for some reason.  I would also consider making the image an "embedded resource" as it would be easier to locate at runtime